# mysql string into IN Clause splitting string or something?

Tags: mysql, string, sql-in

I need to wright function which  will take string of ids like

> ('id1,id2,id3...idN')

and then pass it in Clause

call of this function will look like select ('id1,id2,id3...idN')

inside of function its doing select like this

> select * from table where id in (@string)

if i am passing string as string its not working string looks like `'8409 , 8410, 8414, 8416, 10284, 8408'` , how to pass it as individual ids , not as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is formatted like `8409 , 8410, 8414, 8416, 10284, 8408`,then another choice is using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(',','string of id',',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',id,',%')
```

---

**[FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)()** might also helpful to you

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,'string of id');
```